# How can I add a new field in model when I already have a datamigration in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-migrations

I have a migrations come from the work of another person, and I'm in on a code base controlled by the version too. I created a migration file after adding a new field but the problem is in the data migration (0003_datamigration_initial_service_configuration.py)that is created before through the function get_or_create () is executed in the head of the list while my migration file data in the end I should not change a migration already developed.

This is my list of migrations

- 0001_initial.py
- 0002_datamigration_initial_users_list.py
- 0003_datamigration_initial_mymodel.py
- ...
- 0015.addnewfield

0003_datamigration_initial_mymodel.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations
from ..models import MyModel

def create_initial_mymodel(apps, schema_editor):
    current_product_type, created = MyModel.objects.get_or_create()
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('myapp', '0002_datamigration_initial_users_list'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_initial_mymodel),
    ]
```

Rhe error is `no such column named new_field`

How can I fix the problem without editing any data migrations?

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow uses Markdown -- you don't need all of the html tags in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `apps.get_model` to get the `MyModel` model, instead of importing it directly.

```
def create_initial_mymodel_forward(apps, schema_editor):
    MyModel = apps.get_model('myapp', 'MyModel')
    current_product_type, created = MyModel.objects.get_or_create()
```

Using `apps.get_model` will load a historical version of the model with the correct fields.

Comment: I tried but I had an error like that :    app_label, model_name = app_label.split('.')
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: You need to specify the app and model when you call `get_model()`.